# DDoS attacks on SSL/TLS

Tags: tls, ddos

Upon receiving a `ClientHello` message, most of the time a web server (and without authenticating the client) performs a diffie-hellman exponential modular operation to **compute and save** the `f = g^a mod p` which he would communicate back to the client in its `ServerKeyExchange` message. Does not that make the server vulnerable to DDoS attacks ? Does the protocol implement a mechanism to mitigate this sort of attacks ?

Comment: I'm not entirely sure on this, but I think you are wrong on the authentication part. Don't servers send a `HelloVerifyRequest` to a client before performing this kind of operation?

Answer (score 1):

While there is some overhead in those calculations, this is generally not a problem as DDoS-attacks tend to exceed the network interface's capabilities before the RAM or CPU are overwhelmed with TLS-handshake calculations.

The calculations done for a regular, state of the art dynamic website delivered over HTTP do exceed the TLS handshake calculations by at least an order of magnitude. Thus, counting on the open TLS connections DDoS-ing a webserver seems somewhat superficial. Yes, there is some overhead, yes, it takes up ressources - but not enough to bring the machine(s) to a halt. Just actually making the machines deliver the content can be way worse.

Furthermore, this way DDoS amplification methods can not be utilized - attacking the network connection directly is more promising, from an attackers point of view.

Answer (score 1):

A TLS handshake is computationally expensive compared to a simple TCP connection. And, for some ciphers the expense is mostly on the site of the server as can be seen from the diagram at https://vincent.bernat.im/en/blog/2011-ssl-dos-mitigation which shows a factor of 25 for RSA key exchange with RSA-4096 or factor 7 for RSA key exchange with RSA-2048.

This can be used in DOS attacks and there are also denial of service tools which try to add even more load on the server by doing lots of renegotiations inside a single TLS connection although many server now limit how many renegotiations can be done.

On the other hand, this is just one of several DOS attacks possible at the application layer. Other attacks for example involve just calling a page which does expensive database lookups and thus also ties resources at the server. There are mitigations possible, like limiting the amount of TCP connections, employing certificates and ciphers which are are lean on resources or similar. But, it is impossible to fully stop such attacks since they are not always distinguishable from valid requests, like in the case of the [slashdot effect](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Slashdot_effect).